# How to use Hyperlink in React Router dom Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, react-router-dom, anchor

```
        <li>
          <Link2
            to="https://drive.google.com/file/d/12tcVPBcikN-s_HaD-GdjZrkbygLFv7td/view?usp=sharing">
            Resume
          </Link2>
        </li>
```

I am trying to link My resume drive link but when I click the link it is showing a 404 error.
How do I use hyperlinks in the Link tags?

`import { Link as Link1 } from 'react-scroll'; import { Link as Link2 } from 'react-router-dom';`

I imported the Link as Link2.

```
          <Link2
            to={`https://drive.google.com/file/d/12tcVPBcikN-s_HaD-GdjZrkbygLFv7td/view?usp=sharing`}>
            Resume
          </Link2>
        </li>
```

I tried this way. I also tried to use the Anchor tag inside Link but it only works when I manually right-click and open the link in a new tab.

Comment: `react-router` `Link` components only link to routes the router is managing, i.e. internal pages in the React application. Use a regular anchor `<a>` tag to link to external URLs. Please also [edit] the post to include any code examples/errors/etc as formatted and readable snippets instead of images. Images are not accessible, can be more difficult to read, and are not copy/pasteable in the case readers here attempting to reproduce any issues you describe themselves.

Comment: Stack overflow saying **You need at least 10 reputations to post images.** This is my first post. I can't edit this image for now.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that ***instead*** of posting pictures of your code that you should just post the code.